# Cypress - How to restrict a constant value?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am loading a fixture via constant (there are some reasons why I am not using cy.fixture)
. I loop through a group of users - Cypress._.range(3, 19).

```
        import users from '../../../fixtures/users.json';
        describe('Emergency Code', () => {

        Cypress._.range(3, 19).forEach((k) => {
        const user = users[k]


            it('Should generate Emergency Code for ' + user.Product_Code, function () {

                cy.userAssginDongle(user);
                cy.get('.col-md-12 > .row > .col-md-12 > #sideButtonGroup > .btn:nth-child(2)').click();
                cy.get('.modal-content > .modal-body > .row > .col-md-12 > #copyInput').click();
                cy.get('.modal-content > .modal-body > .row > .col-md-12 >     #copyInput').invoke('val').should('not.be.empty')

            })


        })
        })
```

In users.json there is a field that defines Emergency Code as Yes or No.
"Emergency_Code": "Yes",
"Emergency_Code": "No",

How do I start this test restricting the Fixture JSON data based on this field?
Something like if Emergency is yes: load the user into the test, if it's no, do not load if it's something else do not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user doesn't meet the condition skip that iteration:

```
Cypress._.range(3, 19).forEach((k) => {
        const user = users[k]
        if (user['Emergency_Code'] === 'No') {
          return
        }
```